# Can I access to the current active profile from pom.xml?

Tags: maven

I want to know if there is a way to get the currenct active profile.
I will run the following command:

```
mvn clean deploy -P PRO
```

Is it possible from get this value in the pom.xml file?

E.G. Something like:

```
<...>
    ${project.profile.id}
<...>
```

Comment: Can you explain why you need that? What is the purpose of that? Furthermore why do you have profiles?

Comment: I want to create a string formed with the currect active profile.

I finally get a way to do it by creating a property inside each profile. e.g.:

<current.profile>DEV</...

Is not the cleanest way but it works...

Comment: Why do you need that? What kind of project is this? Which kind of information do you change by the profile?

Comment: It does not matter. The think is, is it possible? Can I get the current active profile in the pom.xml file?